# What is the type of a integral true constant?

Tags: delphi

I'm sorry for asking a very basic question. Consider the following example:

```
const
  c1 = 1;      // Is this Byte or ShortInt?
  c2 = 1234;   // Is this Word or Smallint?
  c3 = 123456; // Is this Cardinal or Integer?
```

After reading this [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants), what I can conclude is that negative value is interpreted as *signed*, and positive value is interpreted as *unsigned*. However, e.g. **123456** (which according to the documentation will be interpreted as `Cardinal`) can also be used in a context of `Integer`, I mean it is used in an `Integer` variable that uses the constant in calculation. Therefore, is the constant **guaranteed** to be always `Cardinal` so that a typecast to `Integer` necessary?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants)? Did it explain this?

Comment: And no, a typed constant is not a constant variable. There's no such things as a constant variable. Something can be one or the other. A variable is permitted to change. A constant is not permitted to change. The "feature" known as *writeable typed constants* is a non-feature that was added by accident and should never be used. Don't be scared of using typed constants. They are to be encouraged. Just don't ever enabled writeable typed constants.

Comment: @David -  The reason for my first question is that I cannot conclude whether an integer constant will be considered as signed or unsigned by Delphi. The reason for my second question is that I see everywhere that people use typed constants, I don't know if there is another way.

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation? That might sound rude, but there it is. I don't understand why people don't read documentation. It seems lazy. Perhaps there's another explanation, but that's how it feels.

Comment: I removed the final question because it is too broad and makes the question off topic. Please don't restore it again. Any time you ask a broad "what is best practice" without framing specific constraints, that's just going to be too broad. If you provided some specific context, an example, that would be fine. But it would need to be in another question. This one is already broad enough.

Comment: After reading this [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Declared_Constants), what I can conclude is that negative value is interpreted as signed, and positive value is interpreted as unsigned. However, e.g. 123456 (which according to the documentation will be interpreted as Cardinal) can also be used in a context of Integer, I mean it is used in an `Integer` variable that uses the constant in calculation. Therefore, is the constant **guaranteed** to be always `Cardinal` so that typecast to `Integer` necessary? Instead of saying rude, why don't just give a link?

Comment: I gave you a link. It's in the very first comment. I suggest that you read the documentation in the future. Ask if you don't understand it.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I didn't see the link when I'm writing my last comment.

Comment: But even so, the real question is why you didn't start with the documentation. That's your take away message here. The documentation is not perfect, but it's your first port of call.

Comment: And my "best practice" question was actually about the best practice declaring and using constants in a variable that uses multi-data types. I didn't start with the documenation because the existence of the documentation that explain this was unexpected. Now, I think such an informaion in the documentation is newly written.

Comment: You can't ask "what is the best practice" without context.

Comment: Can I rephrase my question?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, writable type constants are a remnant from the past, where var declared variables could not be defined at compile time. No excuse to use it now, only for backward compatibility.

Comment: @LURD Agreed they should not be used now. They are an accident. They exist because TP started on systems without memory protection.

Comment: Your edit makes the question even worse. Now it's even more vague and imprecise. You ask many questions, all of them vague. You need to be more narrow and focused and provide some context. Asking for lists of "things to consider" is not appropriate for this site. This is a better fit for a discussion type site. Try the Google+ delphi devs group.

Comment: To understand what I mean, I could answer you question 1, but the other questions are too vague. So I won't answer at all. Which is a shame. Indeed, that I'm talking about multiple questions is a problem. You are expected to ask just one. Have you read the site help?

Comment: @David - No, I have not read the site help yet. I think, inputs needn't to come from only one person. Even a partial answer, people who think it is useful still can upvote it, and an OP may also accepts a partial answer. I have seen many questions in SO asking for suggestions, opinions, etc, and also more than one questions as long as the questions are still very close to the topic that is being asked.

Comment: It's true that other people have made asked unsuitable questions with too many questions lumped together, and asking broad or opinion type questions. That does not make them appropriate. Please do read the help.

Comment: So, what is labelled as Q1 as it stands is good. That's a decent question. You should delete 2 and 3.

Comment: What I did was edit your question again to narrow the focus to the issue of what is the type of an integral true constant. That's a clear and concise question that is well defined. It matches Rudy's existing answer (which I believe is wrong), and it matches my answer. Let's get this question dealt with. Then, if you have further questions, please ask them as separate questions. I do believe that what you have asked is a good question, not least because the documentation is far from accurate. But please don't edit the question to broaden it yet again.

Comment: @LURD: You say that "var declared variables could not be defined at compile time." Local variables still can't have an initial value declared.  Writeable typed constants are still used to emulate the static local variables (variables that will hold their values between function calls) of languages like C. Sure, in almost all respects, they are like global variables, but not WRT scope.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, indeed so. In methods, you can use class var instead of local writable constants, which is clearer.

Comment: A class var is still "class global" which is almost as bad as a real global. A writeable const has a much narrower scope: the function or method it is used in.

Comment: @Rudy If it was possible to declare static locals they'd be useful. But the language doesn't support that. Instead you have to corrupt the meaning of const using directives. To do so in practice becomes ridiculous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Declared_Constants) (XE8 is the latest version as I write this) tells you that *true constants* have a type. However, the documentation is misleading when it comes to specifying what that type actually is. And when I say misleading, I am being somewhat kind.

Were you to read this official [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Declared_Constants) then you would be inclined to believe that unsigned types are preferred to signed types. But this program shows that is not the case:

```
program SO32160057_overloads;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

procedure foo(value: UInt8); overload;
begin
  Writeln('UInt8');
end;

procedure foo(value: UInt16); overload;
begin
  Writeln('UInt16');
end;

procedure foo(value: UInt32); overload;
begin
  Writeln('UInt32');
end;

procedure foo(value: UInt64); overload;
begin
  Writeln('UInt64');
end;

procedure foo(value: Int8); overload;
begin
  Writeln('Int8');
end;

procedure foo(value: Int16); overload;
begin
  Writeln('Int16');
end;

procedure foo(value: Int32); overload;
begin
  Writeln('Int32');
end;

procedure foo(value: Int64); overload;
begin
  Writeln('Int64');
end;

const
  ZeroInt32 = Int32(0);
  ZeroUInt16 = UInt16(0);

begin
  foo(127);
  foo(128);

  foo(32767);
  foo(32768);

  foo(2147483647);
  foo(2147483648);

  foo(9223372036854775807);
  foo(9223372036854775808);

  foo(ZeroInt32);
  foo(ZeroUInt16);
  foo(UInt8(0));
end.
```

The output is:

```
Int8
UInt8
Int16
UInt16
Int32
UInt32
Int64
UInt64
Int32
UInt16
UInt8
```

Let's have a look at another program:

```
program SO32160057_comparisons;

var
  Int8var:  Int8  = 0;
  Int16var: Int16 = 0;
  Int32var: Int32 = 0;

begin
  if Int8var  <              127  then ;
  if Int8var  <              128  then ;  // line 10
  if Int8var  <        Int16(128) then ;  // line 11
  if Int16var <            32767  then ;
  if Int16var <            32768  then ;  // line 13
  if Int16var <      Int32(32768) then ;  // line 14
  if Int32var <       2147483647  then ;
  if Int32var <       2147483648  then ;  // line 16
  if Int32var < Int64(2147483648) then ;
end.
```

The compiler emits the following warnings:

```
(10): W1022 Comparison always evaluates to True
(10): W1023 Comparing signed and unsigned types - widened both operands
(11): W1022 Comparison always evaluates to True
(13): W1022 Comparison always evaluates to True
(13): W1023 Comparing signed and unsigned types - widened both operands
(14): W1022 Comparison always evaluates to True
(16): W1022 Comparison always evaluates to True
(16): W1023 Comparing signed and unsigned types - widened both operands
```

---

So, by my empirical analysis, the compiler looks at the value of an integral literal, and determines its type by finding the first type in the following list which can represent the value:

- `Int8`
- `UInt8`
- `Int16`
- `UInt16`
- `Int32`
- `UInt32`
- `Int64`
- `UInt64`

This rule can be overridden by specifying the type using the typecast syntax. For instance, to declare an `Int32` with value `0` you would write `Int32(0)`.

---

Now let us apply that rule to the concrete example that you give in the question, namely `123456`. According to the rules above, the first type in the list which can represent this value is `Int32`. Also known as `Integer`.

Now, because this is an unsigned type, you might expect that a comparison against an unsigned `UInt32` variable will result in warning W1023, comparing signed and unsigned types. But that is not the case. The compiler recognises that `123456` is a positive value and that we are comparing two positive values. On the other hand, the warning is emitted with `-123456`.

```
program SO32160057_123456;

var
  UInt32var: UInt32 = 0;

begin
  if UInt32var >  123456 then ; // line 7
  if UInt32var > -123456 then ; // line 8
end.
```

The compiler emits the following warnings:

```
(8): W1022 Comparison always evaluates to True
(8): W1023 Comparing signed and unsigned types - widened both operands
```

Comment: In response to your empirical analysis, why, for example, `const cByte = $FF;`  `var iInt: Integer;`  `iInt := cByte;`  is compiled to `mov esi, $000000ff` rather than `movzx esi, $ff`? As seen, `cByte` ($ff) in fact is converted to `Integer` ($000000ff).

Comment: The compiler is just optimising because it knows the values. The end result is identical isn't it? The same 32 bit value ends up in the integer variable. The compiler has more freedom to make such transformations when it is dealing with true constants that it has with variables. By the way, I think the question is a good one now, and I hope we can stick to it in its current form.

Comment: +1 for your empirical analysis that support some true statements in the documentation, but for your comment _the end result is identical_, that does not make the documentation was legal to **guarantee** the type of integral true constants via their table **without** stating an exception to the rule due to compiler optimization. Perhaps the transformation done by compiler is unforeseen by people who play with manual optimization.

Comment: There is no exception to the rule. `iInt` is assigned the correct value is it not? The rule is as I stated. The optimizer is free to write whatever code it likes so long as they end result is indistinguishable. The evidence in my answer is very hard to argue against. Clearly, integral true constants have types, contrary to what Rudy says. The only problem with the docs is that they don't correctly state the rule by which types are chosen.

Comment: You now know what type a true constant has. The question that you should now be asking is, "what influence on my program does that type have?" But that's a new question. ;-)

Comment: If you really doubt that `$ff` has type `UInt8` you need to produce evidence that it is not `UInt8`. The overload test says that it is. What's your evidence that it is not?

Comment: What I wanted to say in my previous comment is that the transformation by the compiler from `$ff` to `$000000ff` having a meaning that the compiler changes a `Byte` constant to `Integer` constant. By the way, I'm so sleepy now. I'm still waiting comments from others. See you later.

Comment: The compiler does not change the type. The Pascal true constant `$ff` has type `UInt8`. Assigning a `UInt8` with that value to an `Int32` sets the value `$000000ff` to the `Int32`. How the compiler puts `$000000ff` into the `Int32` variable is entirely up to it. Since the value is known by the compiler in the case of a constant it's not surprising it chooses a different route.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications.

Comment: Thank you for such an interesting question. I've learnt a lot. Which is why I spend time here. Thanks for helping me learn.

Comment: David, you did not convince me. I already said that, if queried, constants will have a type, but heck, even literals will, if queried, have the same type. That still does not disporve what I said, that constants are, for all practical purposes, "nams for literals".

Comment: @RudyVelthuis You said that they are "more or less untyped and assume a type at the time they are used". The documentation, and the code in my answer, contradict that. I honestly don't care whether or not you are convinced. I am.

Comment: What @Aeoliyan shows is exactly what it means when I say: it depends on the context. `$000000FF` is not a Byte, and yet that is what is assigned to the Integer. No conversion is required, unlike for a variable. There you would see something like `MOVZX EAX,[Somevar];`, which is a conversion. The constant is `$000000FF` when assigned to an integer, but `$FF` when assigned to a byte. In other words, its type depends on the context, or put differently: the constant is untyped, and only assumes a type when that is required, or queried, like in your example.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis No, that's not it at all. `$ff` has type `UInt8`. That is demonstrated by the first program in my answer. The rest of your comment is nonsensical. Of course a conversion is required to assign a `UInt8` to an `Int32`. For a constant the compiler can perform the conversion. For a variable the conversion must be done at runtime. Either way, the same `Int32` value ends up in the variable which is assigned to.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis If you want to argue that declared constants have no type, provide a counter example.

Answer (score 5):

Answering your original questions:

> What is the data type for each of the constants?

They are more or less untyped and assume a type at the time they are used,  like literal values. They do not occupy space and usually have no address unless they must (e.g. strings, sets, etc.). ISTM that you can consider them "symbols representing literals". They can be compared to simple `#define`s in C (IOW, textual replacements) or immediate values in assembler. So `'C'` can be an `AnsiChar`, a `WideChar`, an `AnsiString`, a `WideString` or an `UnicodeString`, and can even be assigned to a `PChar`, `PWideChar` or `PAnsiChar`. The type depends on to what you assign it, just like, well, a literal. The same for integer values or floating point types, set types, etc.

Note that the compiler (and the - IMO incorrect - documentation) will give you a type if you ask, and generally that is the smallest integral type that can hold it, or an `Extended` or `Double` for floating point values, or the enum or set type that it belongs to. But that is, AFAICT, only if you ask.

Only "untyped" or true constants can be used in constant expressions. Typed constants (IOW constants that occupy real space) are, as you say, more or less like "immutable variables" (yes, I know that is an oxymoron), IOW, they have an address, a type, a defined size, but they are just not, er, *variable* or mutable (as David said, forget about writeable typed constants).

I'm sure that some of the people here will thoroughly disagree, but hey, that is how I have always considered true constants, and that view has never failed me.

> How to force a constant to have a specific data type? I mean another way besides *typed constant*, which is actually constant variable if I'm right.

You can give a true constant a type by casting:

```
const
  Bla = UInt64(1234); // $0000000000001234
  Doo = Cardinal(-1); // $FFFFFFFF
  Duh = Shortint(rfReplaceAll);
```

I don't think you can cast to one of the floating point types, though. Such casts are usually prohibited, also for constants (AFAIK, can't test right now).

Expecting a few sharp comments or downvotes now. :-)

### Update

> Therefore, is the constant guaranteed to be always `Cardinal` so that a typecast to `Integer` necessary?

No cast is necessary. The type is not always `Cardinal` anyway, even if the docs say so (as I said, I think they are wrong). Is is simply **as if** you used the literal value `123456` at that spot. You could say that `123456` has a type too, but actually, it is much easier to pretend it doesn't. The type depends on the context and it will probably be compiled as something like

```
        MOV     EAX,123456
        MOV     [TheVariable],EAX
```

How that is interpreted depends on the type of the variable. For instance, if you do:

```
MyDouble := 123456;
```

That does not mean that a `Cardinal` is compiled and a conversion to `Double` must take place. It is compiled as a `Double` value `123456.0` directly. There is probably a conversion, but only inside the compiler.

**So, IMO, stop worrying about the type of such constants. Simple regard them as symbols representing literals and assume they will get the type you expect them to get. You will be seldom wrong.**

## Proof

Take a look at the following piece of code:

```
const
  CHi = 'Hello';
  CInt = $1234;
  CTInt: Word = $1234;

var
  CVInt: Word = $1234;

procedure Test;
var
  A: AnsiString;
  U: UnicodeString;
  I: Integer;
  D, E, F: Double;
begin
  A := CHi;
  U := CHi;
  I := CInt;
  D := CInt;
  E := CTInt;
  F := CVInt;
  Writeln(A, U, I, D); // Just to make this compile.
end;
```

and the disassembly of this:

```
Project44.dpr.25: A := CHi;
00419584 8D45FC           lea eax,[ebp-$04]
00419587 BA40964100       mov edx,$00419640
0041958C E84BE0FEFF       call @LStrLAsg
Project44.dpr.26: U := CHi;
00419591 8D45F8           lea eax,[ebp-$08]
00419594 BA54964100       mov edx,$00419654
00419599 E8A2DFFEFF       call @UStrLAsg
Project44.dpr.27: I := CInt;
0041959E C745F434120000   mov [ebp-$0c],$00001234
Project44.dpr.28: D := CInt;
004195A5 33C0             xor eax,eax
004195A7 8945E8           mov [ebp-$18],eax
004195AA C745EC0034B240   mov [ebp-$14],$40b23400
Project44.dpr.29: E := CTInt;
004195B1 0FB705A0D54100   movzx eax,[$0041d5a0]
004195B8 8945D4           mov [ebp-$2c],eax
004195BB DB45D4           fild dword ptr [ebp-$2c]
004195BE DD5DE0           fstp qword ptr [ebp-$20]
004195C1 9B               wait
Project44.dpr.30: F := CVInt;
004195C2 0FB705A2D54100   movzx eax,[$0041d5a2]
004195C9 8945D4           mov [ebp-$2c],eax
004195CC DB45D4           fild dword ptr [ebp-$2c]
004195CF DD5DD8           fstp qword ptr [ebp-$28]
004195D2 9B               wait
```

As you can see, the value of the string constant is not the same when assigned to an `AnsiString` or to a `UnicodeString`. It is not so easy to copy the data part of the disassembly, so you will have to check that in your own Delphi IDE, but at address `$0041961C`, there is a literal AnsiString (refcount -1) 'Hello', while at address `$00419630`, there is a literal UnicodeString 'Hello'. That means that the constant is compiled as the type that the context requires and that no explicit or implicit conversion (i.e. from `UnicodeString` to `AnsiString`, or from `Word` to `Double`) is required anymore.

Also note that, opposed to the **true** constant, the **typed** constant does require conversion code. The word is loaded as `movzx eax,[$0041d5a0]`, i.e. converted from `Word` to `DWord`, then stored as `DWord`, loaded into the FPU as `DWord` and then stored as 64 bit floating point value (`Double`). That is a conversion you don't see, because it is not needed, for the true constant.

I know that some will say: "well, it is UnicodeString, but the compiler converted it to AnsiString first." IMO, that is like saying: "the original body of the car is grey, but before it is sold (assigned), it must have been painted green." I rather say: "the car that is sold is green, no matter how it got that colour." Sure, literals and constants (IOW, symbols defined in a `const` section), will have a default type, which is given when queried and no specific type is requested, but **for all practical purposes**, it is easiest if you simply treat them as "literals with a name tag", and **not** as of a specific type, IOW **the actual type depends on the context**. How this comes to be doesn't matter.

I think that David and I mean the same, but with different words and different terms. He says: it has type A, but it is converted by the compiler to type B and the result is compiled. That is exactly what I mean with "the type depends on the context." No conversions are required. The same can be seen when assigning the constant of "type `UInt16`" to a `Double`: no conversion is required, it is directly compiled as a 64 bit value and stored in the `Double`. No conversion to be seen, not explicitly nor implicitly. So in that case, the constant declared as `$1234` has a 64 bit floating point value, and is not a `UInt16`.

#### Typed constants

As you can see, the code for the typed constant is 1 to 1 equivalent to the code for the variable, showing that a typed constant can be seen as an "immutable variable", even if that term does not really exist.

Also note that true constants do not even have an address. You can easily try this for yourself:

```
if @CInt = nil then;
```

You will see that it does not compile (`Variable required` error). But now try:

```
if @CTInt = nil then;
```

No such error, which also supports the fact that typed constants are "immutable variables".

Comment: In recent versions it is also possible to create dynamic array constants, which also might be mind boggling.

Comment: @Rudy - In response to your statement, _"They are more or less untyped and assume a type at the time they are used."_, that is what I've been observed so far, therefore the documentation was wrong for claiming constant types that are interpreted based on their value sizes.

Comment: @LURD: Indeed. They are, AFAIK, initialized the same way as "dynamic array constructors", i.e. the array is dimensioned and then the values are assigned one by one. AFAIK, there is no hidden typed constant array that is `Move()`d into the dynarray in one go, but I have no Delphi version here with which I can check that right now.

Comment: Sorry, David, but everything I have seen in the years since Turbo Pascal 3 tells me that what I wrote is correct, **despite what the docs say**. I know that you can query the compiler/runtime for a type, and so you are given one, but that is not how the compiler compiles such values. Just see how a constant `const X = 'C';` is compiled in the various contexts. It does depend on the context what exactly is compiled. Internally, the compiler will hold the value and a type, but it will convert to the required type and compile that for that context.

Comment: @Rudy In order to prove that the docs are wrong, please provide a counter example. An example of code that contradicts what the documents state. That would be, for instance, an assignment `val := SomeConstant` that behaved differently from `val := SomeVariable` where `SomeVariable` has the same type as the type that the document ascribes to `SomeConstant`. I'll be the first to admit I'm wrong if you can produce that counter example to the docs.

Comment: `Val := SomeVariable` might require code to truncate, zero-extend or sign-extend the variable. This is not necessary for true constants. It is late now, and we will be flying home early tomorrow, and my wife wants to sleep now. But I will try to cook something up on Monday.

Comment: I think what you don't understand is made clear by your final paragraphs. `MyDouble := 123456;` Yes, `123456` has type `Cardinal`. As an optimisation the compiler converts that to a floating point value, rather than having that conversion done at run time. But the observable result is the same. It's wrong to conclude that `123456` is not of type `Cardinal`. The documentation is accurate.

Comment: If the constant 123456 truly has type Cardinal, then we should expect the compiler to warn when it's compared with a signed variable, shouldn't we? I don't recall that happening, though.

Comment: @Rob Why would the compiler warn? It knows the value as well as the type. It can be sure that it is safe.

Comment: How does the compiler know the value of a signed *variable*, @David? When we compare an Integer and a Cardinal, the compiler warns that it's widening both operands because of the comparison between signed and unsigned types, no? If the compiler does the conversion *silently* and at compile time for constants (as opposed to variables, where it warns), then what's the use of saying the constant has a type at all? I think it's better to instead think of it as though the constant has whatever type it needs to have based on the context at any given point in the code.

Comment: @Rob It knows the value of the constant. There it knows that widening is not necessary.

Comment: @David, how is that enough to compile a comparison of the form `IntegerVariable < TrueConstant`? Both operands need to have the same type. If `TrueConstant` has type Cardinal, then what common type will the compiler use? Int64, right? When both sides are variables, the compiler warns about that widening. Does it warn when there's a constant involved, too? As I said, I don't recall seeing that.

Comment: @Rob When one operand is a constant the compiler has extra information. The value of the constant. It is able to choose a common type. It says 123456 can be converted to integer and retain the same value, that's my common type.

Comment: @RobKennedy Actually, What I said in my responses to you is not correct. See my answer. You are quite right that *comparing signed and unsigned types* warnings are emitted in some scenarios. I think my answer makes it pretty clear that integral true constants have types.

Comment: *They are more or less untyped and assume a type at the time they are used, like literal values.* That is clearly wrong as the examples in my answer show. *They can be compared to simple #defines in C (IOW, textual replacements).* The pre-processor is just textual replacement. There's no textual replacement going on in the declaration of a Delphi true constant. What's more, C literals have type. `0` has type `int`, `0u` has type `unsigned int` and so on.

Comment: Regarding the side issue of dynamic array constants, you said: *AFAIK, initialized the same way as "dynamic array constructors", i.e. the array is dimensioned and then the values are assigned one by one. AFAIK, there is no hidden typed constant array that is Move()d into the dynarray in one go*. I'm sure I've explained this to you before, but that is wrong too. There is a typed constant array that is built by the compiler. And it is copied into the dynarray in one go. These constant dynamic arrays have negative ref count, just like constant strings.

Comment: @Rudy - Thank you. I find your explanation was useful anyway.

Comment: @David: I can't and couldn't check that right now (no access to anything but XE4 which does not have that yet). That is why I wrote: "AFAIK".

Comment: True constants may not have the same inner workings as `#define`s, but the result is exactly the same. True constants are symbolic values, i.e. "named literals". If you treat them like that, for *ALL* practical purposes, that is how you can see them, no matter how this works internally. If you write `MyInteger := MyConstant`, even if that constant is officially a Cardinal, there is no conversion going on, or widening. It is compiled as integer directly. That is exactly what I mean with "depends on the context".

Comment: The same with  `const CHello = 'Hello';`. That is compiled as UnicodeString or AnsiString, or both, depending on the context, on how it is used. No conversion from one type to the other is necessary, when you assign those. `myAnsiString := CHello;` will assign an AnsiString constant, while `MyUnicodeString := CHello;`, i.e. *the same* constant will assign a UnicodeString constant. That is what I mean with "depends on context"

Comment: In other words: if you treat them as "named literals", it will simply work as expected.

Comment: This is utter nonsense. Read the C standard. When you will do so you will learn that literals have types. If they did not have types, then the compiler would have no basis for performing conversions. And it's just the same in Delphi. The compiler needs to know the type of a declared constant in order to know how to perform a conversion.

Comment: The C standard is not relevant for Delphi. In C, they may have types. In Delphi, true constants (and literals) assume the type that is necessary, i.e. $1234 is an Integer when assigned to an Integer, it is not a Word. Just like `'Hello'`is of type AnsiString when assigned to an AnsiString, and of type UnicodeString when assigned to a UnicodeString. So constants (and literals) may have *default* types, but you can regard true constants as untyped. They assume the type that is necessary in a certain context, like literals.And constants can be regarded as "named literals" or "names for literals".

Comment: The compiler does not compile any conversions. That is exactly what i mean with "the type depends on the context". A true constant is compiled such that no conversion is required. That is why assigning 255 to an Integer does not require a conversion, it is compiled as $000000FF immediately, and not as a Byte. The same for all other true constants. No conversion required, the type is adjusted to the context. That is how true constants differ from variables, which have an address and a type.

Comment: "The C standard is not relevant for Delphi." It was you that started talking about C. Read it in your answer. "They may have types". That's wrong. They **do** have types.

Comment: Back to Delphi. We are talking about integral true constants. Let's keep to them and leave strings out of it. Integral true constants clearly have a type. The documentation says so. And the overload resolution shown in my argument shows that is the case. The compiler warnings about signed and unsigned comparisons also shows that is the case. You don't want to listen and are simply ignoring evidence that is inconvenient to your viewpoint.

Comment: "A true constant is compiled such that no conversion is required." Not so. The compiler performs any conversions that are needed.

Comment: The compiler directly compiles the right type and value and no conversion is required anymore. How the compiler does that internally is completely irrelevant. The end result is that no conversion is required. -- In other words: I see a car with a green body, you see a car with a grey body that is converted to green. The end result is the same and no painting is required.

Comment: I already said that if you request a type, one is assumed, and that is what you see for the overloads with the literals and the consts. The docs do not tell that the right type for the context is compiled directly, and that no conversion (implicit or explicit, at runtime) is required anymore. How the compiler stores such contants in its own parse tree and how it achieves assigning a 64 floating point value to the Double directly when assigning a value of $1234 (which is a Word, according to the docs) is totally irrelevant. No conversion to be seen anywhere.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis The fact that the conversion is performed by the compiler, and you can't see it, does not mean that there was no conversion. It happened in the compiler. Of course you can't see it. Looking at the output of the compiler is pointless. Naturally there's nothing to see there. Strings are irrelevant to the question, which was about integral constants. The asker wanted to know if they had types. You said that they did not. The code in my answer contradicts that.

Comment: The fact that `someVar := 1` has the same end result irrespective of the type of `1` does not mean that `1` has no type. For sure, its type is not pertinent for `someVar := 1`. But it is pertinent in some scenarios. Overloading is one such scenario. Comparison is another. The bottom line is that you appear to be arguing that since the type of a constant can be safely ignored some of the time, that implies that a constant has no type. The reality is that constants have types, and those types are important sometimes, but not always.

Comment: Th fact that it is not visible means we don't know how the compiler got to that value and so it is totally irrelevant. What gets compiled is what counts, and that is that  the constant is compiled as a 64 bit floating point value, directly stored into the Double. So **at that point** (IOW, in that context), the constant **has a 64 bit floating point value**, and **not a 16 bit unsigned integer value**. I know what you mean that it must have been converted somewhere, but not in the generated code. So, in other words, the value and type of the constant `CInt` **depends on where it is used**.

Comment: In other words, what counts is what is compiled (and something that has a 64 IEEE-whatitsnumber floating point value has the type Double), not what the compiler has to do internally to calculate the bits and bytes to be compiled. If I had to write a compiler, I would store each value as 32 bit integer or 64 bit integer, whatever is needed, and then take from that what I need for the situation. **Fact is that what is compiled as a constant differs depending on the situation, and that is what I have been saying all the time.**

Comment: That's the wrong way to think about it. Clearly the constants have types. That's undeniable given the code in my answer.

Comment: It is the only way to think about it. This has always been the plain and simple principle of Delphi: the compiler is is the language. What counts is what is compiled, not what the docs say, nor how it came to be compiled. And a true constant is compiled as the type that is needed in a certain context and that can be different types for the same constant. See my Ansi/UnicodeString example, see my Word/Double example. No conversion code has to be compiled, and that makes the constant a true (as opposed to a *typed*) constant.

Comment: The code in your answer merely displays what I have said: if queried, you will of course get a type. That is of course necessary for the overloads, and the other code in your answer. Your code does not contradict what I wrote, i.e. that they are in priciple untyped, and that the *actual* type depends on the context in which it is used. My code clearly demonstrates that.

Comment: The fact that some operations are not affected by the type of a true constant does not mean that a true constant does not have a type. That's what you are confused about. It's true that the type of the constant `0` matters not when you write `someVar := 0`. But `0` has a type. It is `Int8`. Your attempts to deny that are ridiculous. You so-called proofs prove nothing. All the examples you give relating to integral true constants are perfectly explained by the compiler performing the conversion.

Comment: Your arguments that *the compiler is is the language, what counts is what is compiled* is also silly. It denies the possibility of compiler optimisation, something that clearly exists. For instance, the loop counter of a for loop running the wrong way when the loop body does not refer to it.

Comment: Or perhaps more esoterically are you claiming that the evaluation order of terms in an expression is defined by what the compiler emits, rather than being undefined? For instance, you'd claim that the evaluation order of `foo(x) + bar(y)` is whatever the compiler decides? And that's part of the language? Clearly nonsense. But a logical conclusion of what you said.

Comment: Amidst all the confusion in your posts, it seems that you are now agreeing the integral declared constants do have types. Overloading and comparison examples in my answer make that impossible to deny. However, you appear to be clinging to the stance that integral declared constant only have types at those times. At other times they don't. That's a weird mental model.

Comment: Isn't it easier to have a mental model that says the following: 1. They have types. 2. These types define the conversions that take place in the compiler. 3. The compiler emits code that behaves as if the constant was replaced by a variable of that type, holding that value.

Comment: I think the mental model that a const is merely a named literal, and that its **formal** type is generally irrelevant, is the easiest possible. I have used it with success since the days of Turbo Pascal 3 (or actually, even since Acorn ISO Pascal). I have never had to think: "What is the type of 12345 and how is it converted to the right type in `X := 12345;`?", because the compiler would simply use the right type. I know that when X is an integer, an integer is compiled in, as immediate value, and when X is a Single, a Single will be compiled in, without any need for a conversion.

Comment: That mental model is fine up to a point. But to claim that they don't have type is not sustainable. I think you accept now that they do have types. And that much of the time the type is not relevant.

Comment: They don't have a specific type until they are assigned or otherwise used. Then they get the type that is appropriate for the situation. That is what I learned about Pascal constants some 3 decades ago, and that is still true. So `'Hello'` can be a ShortString, an AnsiString or a UnicodeString, dependent on how and where it is used.

Comment: @Rudy That's demonstrably wrong. The question is about integral constants. Stop talking about strings. Context is irrelevant. The type is determined by the value.

Comment: If you don't use @DavidHeffernan I don't get notified. You also routinely ignore any argument that you find inconvenient. Astonishing that you can't accept the evidence that the overloading example provides.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Right, I sometimes forget that and write without attribution. Sorry. I ignore what is irrelevant, indeed. Fact is that `myInt := 1;`, results in an Integer `$00000001` being assigned, and not a Word or Smallint. No conversion has to take place either. so what I wrote holds: **the type of a true constant depends on the context**.

Comment: @David: nothing has been demonstrated that falsifies what I say. And that is true for all true constants, not just for integral ones. If I do `myInt := -1;` then the value `$FFFFFFFF` is assigned, no intermediate conversion from Shortint is required. So there, `-1` has the type Integer, and not Shortint. But if I assign the **same constant** to a Smallint, it has the value `$FFFF` and is of type Smallint. No conversion required again. The same is true for other true constants, integral or not. So I can demonstrate it for strings too.

Comment: You ignore what is not convenient. Like the overloading example. If you considered that you'd be compelled to change your view and admit that you are wrong. That's inconvenient. The fact that -1 can be Int8 and then converted to any other signed integer without losing the value does not imply that no conversion is performed.

Comment: Anyway, you can have this schizophrenic mental model if you wish. It's twisted and needlessly complex. It does work. But you can't possibly credibly deny that declared integral constants have types that are determined by their value after reading the examples in my answer. You just make yourself look stubborn if you continue to do that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: There is nothing schizophrenic about it. The type is what you expect it to be. If assigned to an integer, than 255 is an integer and not a byte.

Comment: And again, the examples that contradict this, that are not convenient, are ignored.

Comment: It's schizophrenic because you need two mental models. Here are your two mental models: 1. The constant has the type of its assignment target. 2. The constant has the type defined by the rules in my answer. Now you can use model 1 for assignment, but you need model 2 in other places, e.g. overload resolution, comparison etc. Alternatively you can simply use mental model 2 everywhere and still be correct.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It is the simplest model I can imagine. You don't need two models. You only need one: the type is what you expect it to be. And **nothing contradicts** this. Actually the fact that different types are assigned, depending on the situation, and no conversion is required *proves* this.

Comment: The mental model is: the constant has the type it must have in a certain situation. Only if that is ambiguous a default type is chosen. Such ambiguities did not exist in Pascal. Only the introduction of certain constructs, like overloads, caused them, and required the "mental model" of a type for things like "3" or "17".

Comment: Again, you simply ignore all evidence that proves inconvenient. You've proved nothing. I'm not going to argue with you anymore because you've shown yourself to have a closed mind and to be incapable of listening to reason.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I do not ignore anything. I have shown what gets compiled, and that is what counts. And it is exatly as I say. it depends on the situation, and is generally the appropriate type. I have shown that for numbers and for strings. You seem to ignore that. But hey, you can go on using your mental model, I will simply assume that the compiler uses the right type for the situation, i.e. that no conversion is required.

Comment: And well, while everyone claims of himself to have an open mind, the truth is that hardly anyone really has. Your mind is, IMO, just as "closed" as mine. <g>

Comment: You might ask yourself how an integral declared constant is stored in DCU file. Not that I hold to your belief that implementation details define the language, but your mental model demands that these are stored textually.

Comment: My mind has been wide open. I've learnt new things and changed my mind in light of the findings. Read my comments with Rob. You've shown absolutely nothing to prove anything. Your belief that the lack of a runtime conversion proves that no conversion was performed at compile time is clearly wrong. You can't sustain that argument.

Comment: You've ignored many things. Including at least the following: 1. Overloads. 2. Comparisons. 3. The possibility that compilers perform conversions to avoid them being done at runtime. 4. Language defined by emitted code, contradicted by examples of compiler optimisation.

Comment: There are two models proposed: 1. Declared integral constants have types, defined by their value, smallest that can represent the value, signed preferred to unsigned. Conversions to other types are performed using the same rules as would apply to variables of the same type as the constant, having the same value. Conversions may be performed by the compiler. 2: Declared integral constants have no type and their behaviour is specified by the code emitted by the compiler.

Comment: Both of those models are accurate, do you agree? I contend that one of these models is more useful than the other.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I thought you were not going to argue with me anymore?

Comment: Apparently I changed my mind. You didn't answer my question though, Is that your way of ending this?

Comment: You misrepresented my model. I will expand on this if I have something better than this iPad to type on.

Comment: OK, better keyboard now. @DavidHeffernan: I did not ignore overloads nor comparisons. But they do not contradict what I have been saying all the time: **true constants have no specific type. The compiler chooses the type depending on the situation** (so when assigned to an Integer, it is an integer, but when assigned to a Double, *the exact same constant* is a double, etc.). **If the situation does not specify a type (e.g. some overloads, comparisons, etc.), then a default type is chosen**. The **proof** for this is the code emitted by the compiler.

Comment: And now I decide that it does not make sense to argue this anymore. I merely wanted to correct the misrepresentation of my "model" (well, not really mine, but actually the one that has been in place since early Pascal). You may think my model is idiotic (or even that I am), or that I don't understand yours, but I can live with that.

Comment: You can't prove how a language works by looking at what the compiler emits. My model results in identical code to yours.  Bolding proof doesn't make it so. Your mental model is ridiculous. It works but it is convoluted, largely by stubbornness. You still ignore questions.

Comment: OK, one more: @DavidHeffernan: You didn't use my name either, but I assume you meant me: The fact that the language does exactly what I say is proof alright. And yes, for Delphi, the emitted code is the proof (unless it is a bug, but I can't call assigning an integer to an integer and a double to a double a bug <g>). It has always been.

Comment: You get notified because it's your post. Thee code that is emitted is consistent with my model. You can't use emitted code to prove anything of this nature. You seem to bee arguing that my model is wrong. What behaviour does it describe incorrectly?

Comment: I am not arguing anymore, as I said.

Comment: You managed to avoid answering all the questions that would have put you in a tricky spot. Well done.

Comment: I don't think I did, but then again, this debate is getting far too long and is not leading anywhere.

Comment: You ignored many questions. Here's one. You seem to be arguing that my model is wrong. What behaviour does it describe incorrectly?

Comment: Have you thought about what happens what you use a true constant as an argument to Format? There is no context there. Context is used by the compiler, when it has it, to perform conversions at compile time rather than at runtime. But the fact that the compiler performs those optimisations doesn't change the type of the constant.

Comment: Are you seriously adding a comment to a discussion from 2015? I'm not going to re-read all of that, sorry. Format accepts an open array of TVarRec.The TVarRec is the context. Not sure how that proves anything.

Comment: FWIW, the original Pascal standard says that a `constant` denotes a *value* that must be evaluatable at compile time.It does not say which type such a constant has (because at that time, it doesn't have one yet -- it only gets a type when it is actually used -- this can be a different type at several places of use). So for all practical purposes, constants do not have a fixed type. They are mere Pascal equivalents of simple C #defines, i.e. names for textual replacements for literals or literal expressions. When "instantiated", they do of course get a type. FWIW, there were no typed constants.