# What is the logic behind the bitwise not operator on constant integer values?

Tags: delphi, integer, delphi-10.2-tokyo, constant-expression

This question may sound silly but I can not understand the idea behind the `not` operator on constant integers. I get the following results:

- `not $FF` => `$FF00`
- `not $FFFF` => `$FFFF0000`
- `not $FFFFFFFF` => `$00`
- `not $FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` => `$00`

The first two values look wrong to me.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Expressions_(Delphi)) states:

> For example, not performs bitwise negation on an integer operand

and later:

> The result of a not operation is of the same type as the operand

This is not in line with the observed behaviour.

Full code example:

```
unit Unit5;

interface

procedure c();

implementation

uses Vcl.Dialogs, System.SysUtils;

procedure Invert(v: ShortInt); overload; begin
  ShowMessage('ShortInt $' + v.ToHexString());
end;

procedure Invert(v: SmallInt); overload; begin
  ShowMessage('SmallInt $' + v.ToHexString());
end;

procedure Invert(v: Integer); overload;
begin
  ShowMessage('Integer $' + v.ToHexString());
end;

procedure c();
const
  byteValue = not $FF; // = $FF00
  wordValue = not $FFFF; // = $FFFF0000
  cardValue = not $FFFFFFFF; // = $00
  uint64Value = not $FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF; // = $00
begin
  Invert(byteValue);
  Invert(wordValue);
  Invert(cardValue);
  Invert(uint64Value);
end;

end.
```

Comment: This question is essentially the same as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160057/what-is-the-type-of-a-integral-true-constant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is free* to pick a suitable type for true constants, if there can be an ambiguity.

You need to help out in this case by using a value typecast:

```
const
   byteValue = Byte(not $FF);  // => $00  (ShortInt)
   wordValue = Word(not $FFFF); // => $00 (ShortInt)
```

To avoid overloaded confusion, since you only offer signed printout alternatives:

```
const
   byteValue = ShortInt(not $FF);  // => $00 (ShortInt)
   wordValue = SmallInt(not $FFFF); // => $0000 (SmallInt)
```

When no direct overloaded procedure matches an ordinal type, it can be difficult to predict which overload the compiler selects.

---

From [Declared_Constants#True_Constants](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#True_Constants):

> The syntax for declaring a true constant is:
>
> ```
> const identifier = constantExpression
> ```
>
> where identifier is any valid identifier and constantExpression is an expression that the compiler can evaluate without executing your program.
>
> If constantExpression returns an ordinal value, you can specify the type of the declared constant using a value typecast.

---

- Free, in the meaning that it follows certain undocumented rules. See Davids's answer: [What is the type of a integral true constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32164628/576719)

---

Added a full test:

```
program Project110;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

procedure Invert(v: ShortInt); overload; begin
  WriteLn('ShortInt $' + v.ToHexString());
end;

procedure Invert(v: SmallInt); overload; begin
  WriteLn('SmallInt $' + v.ToHexString());
end;

procedure Invert(v: Integer); overload;
begin
  WriteLn('Integer $' + v.ToHexString());
end;

procedure Invert(v: Int64); overload;
begin
  WriteLn('Int64 $' + v.ToHexString());
end;
    
procedure c();
const
  byteValue = ShortInt(not $FF); // = ShortInt $00
  wordValue = SmallInt(not $FFFF); // = SmallInt $0000
  cardValue = Integer(not $FFFFFFFF); // = Integer $00000000
  uint64Value = Int64(not $FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF); // = Int64 $0000000000000000
begin
  Invert(byteValue);
  Invert(wordValue);
  Invert(cardValue);
  Invert(uint64Value);
end;

begin
  c;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm afraid your edit is wrong. The compiler picks the `ShortInt` overload in this case.

Comment: I added a value typecast that matches your overloaded functions types alternatives as well. It is not always easy to know which overload the compiler will select.

Comment: To quote @DavidHeffernan: *"In fact the documentation of the overloading rules is incomplete and the only way to fully understand the compiler's behaviour is by reverse engineering."*

Comment: this question is highly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160057/what-is-the-type-of-a-integral-true-constant

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer. Unfortunately, there is no _detailed_ ObjectPascal specification to look up such things...

Comment: In this case the documentation is wrong as well, but David sorted out the correct compiler type inference logic for type constants in his linked answer.